# Can I use method chaining to delete rows with a if-else condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, method-chaining

Right now my df looks like this (I shorten it cause there are 20 rows).

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'Country': ["Uruguay", "Italy", "France"], 'Winner': ["Uruguay", "Italy", "France"]})
```

```
def f(row):
    if row['Country'] in row['Winner']:
        val = False
    else:
        val = True
    return val

df["AwayTeam"]=df.apply(f, axis=1)
df
```

I want to delete all the rows when AwayTeam=False. Everything's fine, until I was told that I need to build a **method chain**.

```
#Not Chained
df.drop(df[df['AwayTeam'] == False].index, inplace = True)
df = df.drop("AwayTeam", axis=1)
df
#Done for now
```

This is what I tried

```
df=(
    df.drop(
    df[df['AwayTeam'] == False].index, inplace = True)
    .drop("AwayTeam", axis=1)
)
df
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `inplace` argument.

```
df = df.drop(df[df["AwayTeam"] == False].index).drop("AwayTeam", axis=1)
```

If it's set to `True`, the `drop` method will do the [operation inplace and return `None`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html#pandas-dataframe-drop), Which means that your method chain will evaluate like this,

```
df = None.drop("AwayTeam", axis=1)
```

When it's `False`(Which is the default value) the operation will always return a copy of the dataframe so that you can apply other methods on it(method chaining).